# How to update Key Vault Secrets with function app default key and service bus connection string using PowerShell script

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I want to update the key vault secret values by getting the function app default key and service bus connection string using PowerShell/CLI script.

So, can anyone please help me out on this issue.

Comment: Your question is not well-formed.  Please review it and give more details.

Comment: @Pradeep - Do you want to access key vault secrets through function app or you want to update the key vault secrets, service bus conn string using PowerShell?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, I want to read the function app default key and service connection string values and then update the secrets in azure key vault using PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above requirement, We have written the below PowerShell script to pull the function app key value (default & MasterKey), function app application setting (Azure webjob storage) value.

Using those key values the script will create a secrets in the respective key vault.

**Here is the PowerShell Script:**

```
$accountInfo = az account show
$accountInfoObject = $accountInfo | ConvertFrom-Json
$subscriptionId  = $accountInfoObject.id

$resourceGroup = <ResourceGroupName>
$functionName = <functionName>
$vaultname=<vaultName>

$functionkeylist = az rest --method post --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$functionName/host/default/listKeys?api-version=2018-11-01"
$keylistobject = $functionkeylist | ConvertFrom-Json

##To pull the functionapp specific setting 

$appsetting=az functionapp config appsettings list --name $functionName --resource-group $resourceGroup --query "[?name=='AzureWebJobsStorage'].{Value:value}" -o tsv ##pulling specific functionappsetting

##This block will create the secrets for specific app setting & functionapp key

az keyvault secret set --name $functionName'defaultkey' --vault-name $vaultname --value $keylistobject.functionKeys.default 
az keyvault secret set --name $functionName'masterkey' --vault-name $vaultname --value $keylistobject.masterKey 
az keyvault secret set --name $functionName'webappstorage' --vault-name $vaultname --value $appsetting
```

**Note:**

In the above PowerShell we have pulled existing app setting `AzureWebJobStorage` created a secret in the keyvault. would suggest you change the `$appsettings` block with the respective functionapp  appsetting to create a secret in keyvault.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

**Updated Answer:**

Add the below code to above PowerShell script which will  pull the service bus connection string app setting of functionapp & will store connection string value as secret in key vault.

```
$servucebusappsetting=az functionapp config appsettings list --name $functionName --resource-group $resourceGroup --query "[?name=='azfapsb_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS'].{Value:value}" -o tsv ##app setting of  service connection string will be in the format (<servicebusName>_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS)

az keyvault secret set --name $functionName'ServiceBusConnectionString' --vault-name $vaultname --value $servucebusappsetting
```

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh, If possible update the above script by getting the service bus connection string and then update the secret value in azure key vault.

Comment: @Pradeep - please find the above updated answer block , which will pull the service bus connection string & to create a secret in the keyvault

Comment: I want to read the primary connection string from azure service bus namespace. But not from function app settings. And then update it into the key vault.

Comment: @Pradeep - use the below cmdlets to pull SB Connection String & update them to key vault as secret. 
*****
$sbContStr=az servicebus namespace authorization-rule keys list --namespace-name <sbNamespace> --resource-group <resource-group> --name RootManageSharedAccessKey --query primaryConnectionString -o tsv ## Here RootManageSharedAccessKey is default authorization rule get created when we provision Service bus
)
az keyvault secret set --name 'sbcontStr' --vault-name $vaultname --value $sbContStr

******

Comment: Reference documentation to list  [service bus connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/namespace/authorization-rule/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az_servicebus_namespace_authorization_rule_keys_list)